# how to add quantity of products and update total in cart using django?

Tags: python, django, cart

I have cart model and product model 
this code work fine to add each product one time into cart ,but I wanna be able to add quantity of a product and update the total after added but I'm not sure where I should add the quantity field any ideas ? 
My cart model :-

```
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
           new_obj = False
           cart_obj = qs.first()
        else:
           cart_obj = Cart.objects.new()
           new_obj = True
           request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
       return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self):
        return self.model.objects.create()

class Cart(models.Model):
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

cart views.py file:-

```
def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    context = {
        'cart': cart_obj,
    }
   return render(request, "carts/home.html", context)

def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            item = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("show message to user, product doesn't exist")
            return redirect("carts:cart")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        if item in cart_obj.products.all():
            cart_obj.products.remove(item)
        else:
            cart_obj.products.add(item)
   return redirect("carts:cart")
```

I update the subtotal of the cart using m2m_changed signal and then using pre_save signal to add a fixed shipping cost and update total

```
def m2m_changed_cart_receiver(sender, instance, action, *args, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_clear':
        products = instance.products.all()
        total = 0
        for x in products:
            total += x.price
        if instance.subtotal != total:
            instance.subtotal = total
            instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(m2m_changed_cart_receiver, sender=Cart.products.through)



def pre_save_cart_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.subtotal > 0:
        instance.total = instance.subtotal + 50 #shiping cost
    else:
        instance.total = 0.00

pre_save.connect(pre_save_cart_receiver, sender=Cart)
```

What I want is adding quantity and update it using a signal like this but I don't know where should I add this quantity field , it should be for every product in the cart.
example:-

```
Cart 1 contains 2 products
product 1 (quantity 2) price of the unit is 50 , total = 50
product 2 (quantity 3) price of the unit is 100 , total = 200
cart total now is 250
I should take the quantity from the user and then multiple it with the unit price then 
update the total of the cart
```

Please any help on how to do that

Comment: There are many online tutorials for creating an ecommerce website watch any one of them .

Comment: I know and I watched a lot of them I came here after watching many tutorials and I already finished a full course for django and ecommerce but at the end we only able to add the product one time into the cart , I want to add quantity I'm just not sure where to play with that

Comment: Did you go  through it        from django.db.models import aggregates, Sum,F                                          https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/23/django-tip-13-f-expressions.html

Comment: If your problem is solved please post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured out a solution for my problem , 
 
maybe it will help someone in the future

I created a new model called CartItem that has item , item_cart, quantity ,

> item_cart is to make sure that the CartItem related to the session cart.

**and then in cart model updated the products field to be like this:**

```
  products    = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True)
```

**in the cart_add view I get the product_id and the quantity from a form in the template that has 2 inputs fields one for quantity and a hidden one for the product id:**

```
product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
quantity = request.POST.get('quantity_field')
```

**then when clicked add to cart I create a new CartItem for this session cart like this:**

```
cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
item = CartItem.objects.create(item=product,item_cart=cart_obj, quantity=quantity)
```

**then finally added the item to the cart like this:**

```
cart_obj.products.add(item)
```

*I hope that will help any one :)*